# Can I use Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder with Wowza Streaming Engine?

Tags: flash, adobe, wowza

I was successfully able to use vlc player as a live stream encoder with Wowza Streaming Engine by following this tutorial https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-vlc-as-a-live-stream-encoder-with-wowza-media-server-mpeg-ts. Now I want to do the same with Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder and Wowza Streaming Engine. Is it possible? Also if I target end users with desktops, which live encoder should I use with Wowza Streaming Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously you can use Adobe FMLE to encode the stream.

It does not matter what encoder you use. The client do not know anything about your encoder. Wowza accept input stream as rtmp, or rtsp.

Wowza is a multiprotocol server that offers multiple options to deliver the video (HLS, rtmp, HDS,...)

Have a look to the Wowza Specification https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine/specifications

Comment: thanks for the reply. However I tried FMLE to connect to Wowza media server. But was not able to.

Comment: I guess some of the settings might be incorrect: (Publishing point, authentication, or maybe video/audio settings). But in general, yes FMLE should work with Wowza without problems. Check Wowza logs and FMLE output to see more details.

Comment: i've installed wowza trial version on my local machine as well as FMLE. Moreover the FMLE interface only gives me option to stream to FMS and not Wowza streaming engine

Comment: FMLE says "Stream to Flash Media Server" but you can use Wowza too, :-) just enable the checkbox, and set the ip/url of your wowza. Wowza trial should work for testing.

Comment: I am trying right now but it wont accept the credentials i use for wowza

Comment: Scratch that.. was finally able to do the same. Thanks :)

Comment: I have some more questions regarding live stream recording with wowza. Could you help me out please?

Comment: why do not you open new questions here in SO?, I will be happy to help you and the whole community :-)

Comment: I've posted the new question. Can you have a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505926/video-streaming-recording-solution-wowza-streaming-engine-flash-media-live-e